# Parse a string for a particular time format and to print that onto a file in C

Tags: c

Here the intention is to parse the input file and if the file contains time in any line ,I need to extract the time info only from that line and write to output file ,rest lines keep as it is .I am using fgets to get line by line and sscanf to see the required pattern ,but that giving seg fault.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   FILE *fIn,*fOut;
   char buffer[100];
   int Hr=0,Min=0,Sec=0,MSec=0;
   fIn = fopen("dat.txt","r+");
   fOut= fopen("kel.txt","w+");
   if (fIn == NULL) {
      printf("Can't open input file in.list!\n");
      exit(1);
   }
   while(!feof(fIn))
   {
         fgets(buffer,100,fIn);
#if 1
         if(sscanf(buffer,"%u:%u:%u.%u",Hr,Min,Sec,MSec) ==4)
         {
            fprintf(fOut,"%02u:%02u:%02u.%6u",Hr,Min,Sec,MSec);
            printf("hello");
            continue;
         }
#endif
         fputs(buffer,fOut);
   }
   fclose(fIn);
   fclose(fOut);
}
```

Here is few lines of dat.txt:

```
17:48:22.618782 IP n003-000-000-000.static.ge.com > n003-000-000-000.static.ge.com: ICMP echo request, id 2105, seq 4, length 64
        0x0000:  b870 f414 033b b870 f414 0343 0800 4500
        0x0010:  0054 0000 4000 4001 2e9c 0303 0305 0303
        0x0020:  0303 0800 e69d 0839 0004 43bc 4a52 8d13
        0x0030:  0300 0809 0a0b 0c0d 0e0f 1011 1213 1415
        0x0040:  1617 1819 1a1b 1c1d 1e1f 2021 2223 2425
        0x0050:  2627 2829 2a2b 2c2d 2e2f 3031 3233 3435
        0x0060:  3637
17:48:22.618817 IP n003-000-000-000.static.ge.com > n003-000-000-000.static.ge.com: ICMP echo reply, id 2105, seq 4, length 64
        0x0000:  b870 f414 0343 b870 f414 033b 0800 4500
        0x0010:  0054 7821 0000 4001 f67a 0303 0303 0303
        0x0020:  0305 0000 ee9d 0839 0004 43bc 4a52 8d13
        0x0030:  0300 0809 0a0b 0c0d 0e0f 1011 1213 1415
        0x0040:  1617 1819 1a1b 1c1d 1e1f 2021 2223 2425
        0x0050:  2627 2829 2a2b 2c2d 2e2f 3031 3233 3435
        0x0060:  3637
```

Actualy I am on a phase of trying to write the above packets to text2pcap understandable form .I should use c code [od and hexdump wont be used ].

Comment: If you use `%u` with `sscanf`, your parameters should have type `unsigned int`, not `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass **addresses** where `sscanf` to store values:

```
if(sscanf(buffer,"%u:%u:%u.%u", &Hr, &Min, &Sec, &MSec) ==4)
                                ^    ^     ^     ^
```

Also, as user694733 points out, if they're unsigned (implied by `%u`, use `unsigned int Hr` and so on).

Comment: So ashamed of myself. %u was a make over ,I was using %d ,now workng .

Comment: Any input on text2pcap form
        0x0000:  b870 f414 0343 b870 
000000 b8 70 f4 14 03 43 b8 70
1. no leading white space
2. ox and : shouldnt be there
3. two white space substitue with single 
4. two byte to 1 byte format